# Wrong offset for TimeZone casablanca (java)

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to build a date (29/07/2014 at 02:55:08 am) in Casablanca timezone and got this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(Unknown Source)

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Casablanca"));
cal.setLenient(false);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 29);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6); // July
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 8);
cal.getTime();
```

The exception is thrown with jre 1.7.0_71 and 1.8.0_20 , but not with 1.6.0_30.

As far as I know, there is no daylight saving change occuring at that particular time. Any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JRE is not *always* updated with the latest time zone data.  To stay current, you *must* use the TZUpdater utility.  Oracle publishes [the list of time zone updates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) for both JRE and TZUpdater.  It shows that the last JRE update (as of my writing this) was in release 65 for Java 7, and release 11 for Java 8 - and it was made with version 2014c of tzdata.

If we look at [the sources for tzdata at version 2014c](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014c/africa#L983-L985), we can see that the guess at that time for Morocco did indeed guess the Ramadan DST suspension from Jun 29 - Jul 29.

```
Rule    Morocco 2014    only    -   Jun  29      3:00   0       -
Rule    Morocco 2014    only    -   Jul  29      2:00   1:00    S
```

It was of course later updated to the values shown in Chris's answer, when Egypt finally announced the real dates.

You can see some of the breadcrumbs from the original guesswork [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/egypt-reintroduces-dst-2014.html) and there are many discussions in the tz list archives about Egypt, [starting in May](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2014-May/thread.html) and continuing through to July.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did not known about the TZUpdater utility, it solves the problem.

Comment: @JDM Matt's answer is really good, and you should click on the big green tick below the voting buttons to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It actually does correspond to a daylight savings change. In Morocco, daylight savings is suspended during Ramadan. See http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/egypt-morocco-dst-ramadan-2014.html for more information.

The timezone data entry for 2014 is as follows:

```
Rule    Morocco 2014    only    -       Jun     28       3:00   0       -
Rule    Morocco 2014    only    -       Aug      2       2:00   1:00    S
```

Comment: according to tz data, 29/07/2014 at 02:55:08 am should be a valid timestamp ? (Calendar.MONTH is indexed by 0 so 6 is July)