# HOUR_OF_DAY error in Talend?

Tags: java, talend

I am getting below error while importing data from text file to CSV file output.
I checked the date I did not find any error in dates. Can anybody explain what is HOUR_OF_DAY error.

Job;-

```
tFileInputdelimited --> tmap -- > tFileOutputdelimited
```

Error :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2764)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:2606)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1118)
at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1091)
at routines.system.FastDateParser$DateTimeParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:222)
at routines.system.ParserUtils.parseTo_Date(ParserUtils.java:282)
at responsys.load_responses_opt_out_hist_0_1.Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.tFileList_1Process(Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.java:2124)
at responsys.load_responses_opt_out_hist_0_1.Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.tFileDelete_1Process(Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.java:547)
at responsys.load_responses_opt_out_hist_0_1.Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.runJobInTOS(Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.java:4338)
at responsys.load_responses_opt_out_hist_0_1.Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.main(Load_Responses_OPT_OUT_Hist.java:4203)
Unparseable date: "2014-03-09 02:11:11"
```

Comment: Take a look at this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925035/wrong-offset-for-timezone-casablanca-java

Comment: pls check the schema of file input and file output and tmap..give details about it - and what transformation are you doing in tMap?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deselect the "check date" in component advanced settings.